# mysql query and index

Tags: mysql, indexing

Does this query will be faster with a index on "t.type1" and "x.type1" or only index on "x.type1" is enought?

`SELECT t.id, x.id
FROM t
INNER JOIN x ON x.type1=t.type1
WHERE t.id=1`

Comment: Have you tried? A better question would have been: "I've made a small benchmark and found that this query is slower if I change indexes. Why is that?"

Comment: How many rows does your table have? How many rows will typically have t.id=1?

Answer (score 2):

You should have an index on `t.id` (presumably it is the primary key?) and an index on `x.type1`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, how many records do you have and how many unique values you have in these columns? Just use EXPLAIN to see what the database does and do this with and without indexes. You'll see the difference.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Frank.
I thought Mysql fetch rows from table "t" which are corresponding to the "WHERE" clause and after this join table "x" on the "t.type1" value, so "t.type1" doen't need to be an index. Could you told how Mysql proceed with this query?

Comment: @parm.95 use `EXPLAIN` to find this out!